# Automatic column hiding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables, multiple-columns

My table is too big making the window scrollable(hence the two pictures). I want to hide some of my columns that way when a user clicks on the green button the remaining columns will be displayed underneath. How would I accomplish this?

I tried taking a look at this website to find my solution [Column Hiding](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/auto.html) Right now I'm using details-control to style and hide my columns but my function format doesn't seem to working. None of my data from my columns seem to be displaying and only the name of the first column "GroupClass is displaying. The columns I want to hide is everything to the right of Crisis Appt Time. I believe the issue lies in my function "format" at the bottom of my code.

```
    @model ClinicalReferralSearchViewModel
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Clinical Referral Search";
}

@{
    string tableid = "tableid_ClinicalRefSearch";
}
    <style>
        td.details-control {
            background: url('../../images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        tr.shown td.details-control {
            background: url('../../images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
        }
    </style>
    <table id="@tableid" class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.PrimaryClient)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.PriorTherapistName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.PriorDatesSeen)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.IsNewDirectionSA)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.IsDVChildCounsel)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.IsCrisisAppt)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.DateCreated)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptTherapistName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptTime)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.GroupClass)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.ClientAvailability)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.AssignmentNotes)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.ContactNotes)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => searchResultViewModel.ReferralDescription)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @* Contents *@
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>


<script type="text/javascript">

        if (typeof (vh) === "undefined") vh = {};
        if (typeof (vh.clinicalref) === "undefined") vh.clinicalref = {};

        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
             $('#@tableid tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = vh.clinicalref._table.row(tr);
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });

        (function () {
        "use strict";
        this._table = {};
        this.cleared = false;
        this.refresh = function () {
            this._table.ajax.reload();

        },
        },
            this.dataTableSet = function () {
            this._table = $("#@tableid").DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                paging: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                    heightMatch: 'auto'
                },
                deferRender: true,
                searching: false,
                responsive: true,
                stateSave: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Search", "ClinicalReferrals")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: function (d) {


                        d.@nameof(Model.PrimaryClient) = $("#@nameof(Model.PrimaryClient)").val(),
                            d.@nameof(Model.DateCreatedStart) = $("#@nameof(Model.DateCreatedStart)").val(),
                            d.@nameof(Model.DateCreatedEnd) = $("#@nameof(Model.DateCreatedEnd)").val(),
                            d.@nameof(Model.IsCrisisAppt) = $("#@nameof(Model.IsCrisisAppt)").val(),
                            d.Cleared = vh.clinicalref.cleared;

                        return acc.antiForgery.addToken(d);
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        vh.button.loading("#@btnSearch");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        vh.tooltips.hide();
                        vh.button.reset("#@btnSearch");
                    }
                },

                drawCallback: function () {
                    vh.tooltips.enable();
                },

                columns: [
                    {
                        className: 'details-control',
                        orderable: false,
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: ''
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.PrimaryClient)',
                        orderable: false,
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                const secondary = row['@nameof(searchResultViewModel.SecondaryClient)'];
                                var clients = 'Primary Client: ' + data;
                                if (secondary != null) {
                                    clients = clients + '<br/>';
                                    clients = clients + 'Secondary Client: ' + secondary;
                                }
                                return clients;
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.PriorTherapistName)',
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.PriorDatesSeen)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            if (data) {
                                var mDate = moment(data);
                                return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("l") : "";
                            }
                            else return null;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.IsNewDirectionSA)',
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            if (data)
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" checked disabled/>`
                            else
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" disabled/>`
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.IsDVChildCounsel)',
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            if (data)
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" checked disabled/>`
                            else
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" disabled/>`
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.IsCrisisAppt)',
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            if (data)
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" checked disabled/>`
                            else
                                return `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-field" disabled/>`
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.DateCreated)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            if (data) {
                                var mDate = moment(data);
                                return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("l") : "";
                            }
                            else return null;
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptTherapistName)',
                    },
                     {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptDate)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            if (data) {
                                var mDate = moment(data);
                                return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("l") : "";
                            }
                            else return null;
                        }
                    },
                     {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.CrisisApptTime)',
                         render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                             if (data) {
                                 var mDate = moment(data);
                                 return (mDate && mDate.isValid()) ? mDate.format("LT") : "";
                             }
                             else return null;
                         }
                    },
                      {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.GroupClass)',
                    },
                                          {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.ClientAvailability)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<div class= "scrollingCell">' + data + '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.AssignmentNotes)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<div class= "scrollingCell">' + data + '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.ContactNotes)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<div class= "scrollingCell">' + data + '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.ReferralDescription)',
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<div class= "scrollingCell">' + data + '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: '@nameof(searchResultViewModel.ClientId)',
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            var div = $("<div>");

                            // Details
                            if (data != null) {
                                var link = $("<a>").addClass("btn btn-primary")
                                    .attr("href", `@Url.Action("Details", "Clients")/${data}`)
                                    .attr("data-toggle", "tooltip")
                                    .attr("data-boundary", "window")
                                    .attr("title", "Go to Client Details")
                                    .append($("<i>").addClass("fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"))
                                    .appendTo(div);

                                return $(div).html();
                            }
                            else {
                                var link = $("<a>").addClass("btn btn-primary")
                                    .attr("href", `#`)
                                    .attr("data-toggle", "tooltip")
                                    .attr("data-boundary", "window")
                                    .attr("title", "Referral has no Client Details")
                                    .append($("<i>").addClass("fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"))
                                    .appendTo(div);

                                return $(div).html();

                            }

                        }
                    },
                ],
                order: [[0, "asc"]]
            });
            vh.clinicalref._table.on('draw', function () {
                vh.tooltips.enable();
            });
        }
    }).apply(vh.clinicalref);

    function format(d) {
        var service = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>Group Class</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        for (const rec of d.GroupClass) {
            service = service + '<tr>' + '<td>' + rec.clinicalref + '</td>' + '</tr>';
        }
        service = service + '</table>';
        return service;
    }

</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is a lot of code that you are asking us to look at. Can you strip it down to the smallest amount of code which still demonstrates the issue? And can you present that as a [mre] which we can run for ourselves? The ASP.NET side of things should (I think) be irrelevant for a MRE. Can you hard-code the data, instead?

Comment: Having said that, your question mentions this [column hiding](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/auto.html) technique, which requires the [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension. But on the other hand, your code contains what appears to be techniques taken from this different [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) technique. So, it's hard to see what is really going on... Again, a MRE may help.

Comment: I made an MRE of my application and yes I'm also using child rows in combination with the column hiding

Comment: OK thank you - but I don't see an MRE in the question... Is it available somewhere else?